# update row by row of a table using for loop in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to update/edit details and then save those details into table row by row. for that I just created following Linq query

```
AB_Product_vs_Field insertproductvalue = new AB_Product_vs_Field();

for (int i = 0; i < product.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
{
   insertproductvalue.Product_ID = product.Product_ID;
   insertproductvalue.Field_ID = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID;
   insertproductvalue.Field_Value_EN = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN;
   insertproductvalue.Field_Value_AR = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR;

   db.Entry(insertproductvalue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();
};
```

but then I'm getting following error

> The property 'Field_ID' is part of the object's key information and
>   cannot be modified.

Comment: You need to initialize a new instance of `AB_Product_vs_Field` inside the loop.

Comment: @StephenMuecke how to do that

Comment: teo van kot has just posted the correct answer

Comment: @StephenMuecke can I know the reason to do like that

Comment: Your currently initializing one instance of your `AB_Product_vs_Field`. In the first loop you set its ID and add it to your db context (the `db.Entry()` line). In the following iterations, you modify the ID of the same instance but the instance is now being tracked. You cant change the ID once its been added to the context

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Stephen Muecle say:

```
for (int i = 0; i < product.ListProductFields.Count; i++)
{
   AB_Product_vs_Field insertproductvalue = new AB_Product_vs_Field();
   insertproductvalue.Product_ID = product.Product_ID;
   insertproductvalue.Field_ID = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_ID;
   insertproductvalue.Field_Value_EN = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_EN;
   insertproductvalue.Field_Value_AR = product.ListProductFields[i].Field_Value_AR;
   db.Entry(insertproductvalue).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

};
db.SaveChanges();
```

Also you should notice that i move `SaveChanges` outside the loop. That's better becouse all changes will submit or doesn't submit (If you have error) at once.